# Instagram follow/unfollow code in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

In my phonegap application I am using Instagram API to follow/unfollow. it require POST method of form with one variable "action=follow" or "action=unfollow". when i use POST method using simple form it works fine but it returns JSON.

How do I redirect back to my application? Can I do this in JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue using inapp browser. when follow.unfollow task completes than just clost inapp browser